# ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements - 'UISupportedInterfaceOrientations'

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Im trying to submit my app to the apple store but I am getting a 16 errors after I archive for publishing : This is the first one:

```
    ERROR ITMS-90045: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key 'UISupportedInterfaceOrientations' in 'Payload/Caregiver.iOS.app/Caregiver.iOS' is not supported."
```

I dont know where to start to solve this?

The contents of the Info.plist file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Caregiver</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>Caregiver</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.2</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1.2</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
<string>8.0</string>
<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
</array>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>LaunchScreen</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
<string>Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset</string>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.wisepill.Caregiver</string>

</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I am getting 15 errors - all type :  ERROR ITMS-90045:   "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, key : for UISupportedInterfaceOrientations, UILaunchStoryboardName, XSAppIconAssets, MinimumOSVersion, UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance, CFBundleDisplayName, CFBundleIdentifier, CFBundleName, CFBundleShortVersionString, CFBundleVersion, UIDeviceFamily, UIStatusBarStyle,UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad, LSRequiresIPhoneOS and UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Comment: It seems you didn't use the correct provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

In the Info.plist file in iOS project add this line

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this line already exists in the Info.plist file

Comment: you already get 15 error so i guess that the problem that he don't recognize the info.plist file

Comment: check the properties of the Info.plist file make sure that it set to "None" , if this don't solve the problem can you pasts the full xml code of the Info.plist file

Comment: Hi Houssem, the info.plist file properties "Build Action" is set to "None"

Comment: Thanks Houssem, I have added the contents of the plist file above

Answer (score 0):

I  recreated the provisioning profile and it went through! Clearly, the app store submissions process does not always provide error messages that point to the actual root cause of the issue.